# Sencha touch 2.0 Calendar Plugin Run Issues in production, package and device

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have implemented this calendar in my app developed in sencha touch 2.0 and I face a problem.When I run my application source code in a web browser, Calendar works fine. But when I generate the production & package of the app the calendar not work and following issues occur.Moreover these issues also occur when app run in a device:
 1):   Cell not select in the month view of calendar.
 2):   Next and Previous not work in the month, week and day view of calendar.
 3):   This seems to me that on tap events cannot get bind

Example :

this.element.on({
tap: this.onTableHeaderTap,
scope: this,
delegate: 'td'
});

this.element.on({
tap: this.onTimeSlotTap,
scope: this,
delegate: this.getItemSelector()
});

Please help me to get rid of this hurdle.

I shall be very thank full to you.

Answer (score 1):

Create your class obj like this and add this in your child class constructor:

```
companyCalender = Ext.create('myapp.view.TouchCalendarView',{
                  viewConfig : {
                      mode : 'month',
                      weekStart : 0,
                      value : new Date()
                  }
});
Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config);
Ext.apply(this, config);
myapp.view.CompanyCalender.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments); 
this.add(companyCalender);
```